# How can I define a method with multiple optional arguments in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c

I want to be able to update two sets of identical buttons with one function. Also I don't want to update all the buttons, only some of them.

Can I have a function like this?:

```
-(void) updateFields{
                    updateButton1 : (Bool) x
                    updateButton2 : (Bool) y
                    updateButton3 : (Bool) z }
```

The implementation will look like this:

```
[button1_1 setEnabled:x];
[button1_2 setEnabled:x]; //called only if updateButton1 is given an argument
[button2_1 setEnabled:y];
etc...
```

Comment: Why not pass in an NSArray of UIButtons that you would like to update instead?

Comment: The only gripe I have is that the buttons are duplicates of each other, so [but1_1] and [but1_2] have to be in the same state. Can I do      this in such a way that the elements map to two buttons?

Comment: 1) For the general case I often find passing a dictionary of parms is most flexible and clear.  2) You could pass an NSNumber and pass nil for omitted parms.

Comment: I think I kinda understand, but could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about passing an array of button and an array of boolean wrapped in a NSNumber?

```
- (void)updateButton:(NSArray *)buttons withArray:(NSArray *)enablers {

    // buttons is an array of UIButton
    // enablers is an array of NSNumber created from boolean value

    // Security check
    if(buttons.count != enabler.count) {
        NSLog(@"Error: array have different dimensions");
        return;
    }        

    // Enable buttons
    for(int i=0; i<buttons.count; i++) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)[buttons objectAtIndex:i];
        BOOL enable = [[enablers objectAtIndex:i] boolValue]

        [button setEnabled:enable];
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about doing this, however what if I don't know a state of some button and I don't want to change it, only updating one or two of the buttons I need?

Comment: Just putting in the buttons array only the buttons you need to change, not all of of them :)

Comment: I see, however changing only changing two buttons means passing in 4 UIButtons, since they are duplicates. Can I pass a different array where each element maps to two buttons?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible with primitive data types unless you create objects from them and put them in NSArray or NSDictionary. Other option can be to create a custom object and pass that as argument.

```
- (void)selectButton:(SelectedButton *)iButton {
     if (iButton.type = A) {
     // Handle A
    } else if (iButton.type = B) {
     // Handle B
    } else if (iButton.type = C) {
     // Handle C
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the syntax you're going for makes more sense as a C function

however note that in this example the parameters are NOT optional.

```
void updateButtons(BOOL btn1, BOOL btn2, BOOL btn3){
    button1.enabled = btn1
    button2.enabled = btn2
    button3.enabled = btn3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to create an Objective-C method with a variable argument list, as Matt Gallagher explains in [*Variable argument lists in Cocoa*](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html). Variable argument lists are even used in the Foundation framework, e.g. `+[NSArray arrayWithObjects:...]`.

That said, it's probably a lot less work to pass the list of buttons in your method as an array, particularly given the ease with which one can now create arrays using object literals:

```
[foo updateFields:@[button1, button2, button3]];
```